# Use variables to set timer, as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How can I use variables to set my timer? I want to control delay and repeat as variable. My output acts as if there is nothing set in the timer.

**Not working** variables

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(delay,repeat);
var delay:uint = 100;
var repeat:uint = 60;
```

**Works Fine** no variables

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000,60);
```

**Complete** Unexpected results. Counts to thousands within seconds.

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(delay, repeat);
var delay:uint = 1000;
var repeat:uint = 60;
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, countdown);
function countdown(event:TimerEvent) {
myText.text = String(0 + timer.currentCount);
trace(0 + timer.currentCount);
}
timer.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because you are declaring your variables after you create your timer instance. try...

```
var delay:uint = 1000;
var repeat:uint = 60;
var timer:Timer = new Timer(delay, repeat);
```